# how to serialize data in php?

Tags: php, serialization

I am using serialize() function.
       Here is what I tried

```
$capability='Editor';  
   $id=1;  
   $three=array($capability.";".$id);  
   $abc=serialize($three);  
   print_r($abc);
```

Above code giving me output

```
a:1:{i:0;s:8:"Editor;1";}
```

and I want output in following form

```
a:1:{s:6:"editor";b:1;}
```

How to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: why do you want in that format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first Unserialize your desired output. It says

```
Array
(
    [editor] => 1
)
```

So now we know, you are not building the array correctly. Do

```
$three=array($capability=>$id);
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/688206)**

To produce a Boolean  value you can use TRUE instead of 1.

```
 $id=TRUE;
```

And the result will be

```
a:1:{s:6:"Editor";b:1;}
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/688207)**

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thanks for help.